# Functions keys in windows 7 macbook

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I have a late 2007 MacBook 3,1 with windows 7 x64 installed on it as part of bootcamp. I can't set the function keys to behave as they would on a pc... I have to press fn each time in order to use their original functionality. I don't have any kind of boot camp option under control panel, so I'm puzzled what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have downloaded bootcamp 4 and installed it with BootCamp64.msi and now I have a BootCamp option under control panel. Works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what the problem is, but I expect it might be solved by going to (while it's running Mac OS) System Preferences > Keyboard > "Use all F1, F2 keys, etc. as standard function keys" and toggling it.

That's just a hypothesis; I don't have Boot Camp.

Comment: That can be done from OSX, but not from Windows 7.

Comment: This is true, but I thought maybe it would carry over to the way Windows handles the keyboard. Oh, well!